# How do I add boost to dev-c++

Tags: c++, windows, boost

How do I add boost to dev-c++ or Borland C++ on Windows XP and make a program that accepts regular expressions with it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does it all means ?!?!?!

Comment: I need to know how to use boost in windows

Comment: Did you read the [Installation instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/regex/doc/install.html)? On which part did you get stuck?

Comment: Hmm, Google Translate adds spaces inside "C + +", I think it produced this text.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand right you are using dev-c++ to develop c++ software. Well dev-c++ is old and buggy, I had great success with [Code:Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/). Their Wiki is full of resources with HOW-TO for different things. Here for instance is a quick ref for installing boost: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef

Be prepared to spend like 2-3h to make boost working.